# Preserving thread safety using lambda

Tags: java, multithreading, lambda, thread-safety

I'm trying to update some code to use lambda expressions but I'm having a bit of trouble preserving thread safety.

I have multiple threads running that eventually call the following callback, which has a `synchronized` method that adds some results to a `LinkedList`.

```
final List<Document> mappedDocs = new LinkedList<>();
final MapCallback<Integer, Document> mapCallback = new MapCallback<Integer, Document>() {
    @Override
    public synchronized void done(int file, List<Document> results) {
        mappedDocs.addAll(results);
    }
};
```

However when I convert it to a lambda expression I lose the `synchronized` keyword and I'm not entirely sure how to get it back. I'm now getting a NullPointerException whenever I run my code.

```
final MapCallback<Integer, Document> mapCallback = (int file, List<Document> results) -> mappedDocs.addAll(results);
```

How can I make this thread safe again?

Comment: can't you just not use a lambda?

Comment: @jtahlborn I can. It's just my IDE is telling me I can replace it with a lambda so I thought I'd try.

Comment: i'm going to go with [no](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.27) (see no reference to "synchronized" in there).

Comment: I think it's a bug in the IDE that it lets you do this refactoring without warning you that it's throwing away the synchronization.

Comment: If it has to be synchronized, then you are calling some method of an object or static method of a class. So you can simply use a lock on that object or class like assylias suggested in [the accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26744823/2237467).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You could synchronise it on a different monitor, e.g.:

```
final MapCallback<Integer, Document> mapCallback = (int file, List<Document> results) -> {
  synchronized(mappedDocs) {
    mappedDocs.addAll(results);
  }
};
```

Or alternatively use a thread safe structure, for example a CopyOnWriteArrayList or a BlockingQueue.

Answer (score 3):

I'd strongly recommend making `mappedDocs` be a thread-safe data structure (such as one from `java.util.concurrent`) or perhaps a synchronized wrapper created using `Collections.synchronizedList`.

I think you're lucky that synchronization works using the anonymous inner class. This works because there is exactly one instance of it, and there is no other code that mutates `mappedDocs`.

(Actually you might have a memory visibility problem, even as things stand. If other threads call `MapCallback` to add elements, something else needs to synchronize on `mappedDocs` after its construction and prior to reading the added elements.)

The root of the issue is that an anonymous inner class used this way is kind-of like a function, but since the creation of a new object is manifest, it's tempting to do things like synchronizing on it. But this is quite fragile. If this were refactored so that multiple instances of the AIC were created (e.g., to process documents from multiple sources), or if different AICs are created (e.g., to delete documents from the list if they need reprocessing), synchronizing on individual AIC instances would be completely broken.

Converting `mappedDocs` to a thread-safe data structure or wrapper takes care of the memory visibility issue and the concurrent access issue. This lets you use the simple lambda form, and it lets you introduce new operations on `mappedDocs` without regard to what threads are operating on it.